# C - Caesar Cipher - Abort Trap:6 Error?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am writing a shift cypher program in C. However when I enter about 9 characters into the string, it breaks and the error **Abort trap: 6** appears. 
However it works fine with less than 9 charactesr entered by the user, and the calculation function calculates the cipher and then the output function then outputs the result.

However i am unsure as to why it wont allow the user to enter 9 character or more to cipher shift?

Is it something to do with the pointers because when i have all the code in the main body without functions and pointers, it works perfectly. However when performing the calculation this error occurs if i enter to many characters, however i am unsure why?

**Main body code**

```
here/*Macro constant for input limit*/
#define LIMIT 79


/*function templates*/
void prompt(char * setence , int * shift);
void calculation (char * setence , int shift);
void output (char * setence);

int main ()
{

 char setence[LIMIT];
 int shift;

 //pointers
 char * sent;
 int * sh; 

 sent = &setence[LIMIT];
 sh = &shift;


 /*Ask user for Setence & shift amount for fibbinachi*/
 prompt(sent , sh);


/*calculate sequence */
 calculation(sent , shift);

/*output new result sequence */
 output(sent);

 return 0; }
```

**Prompt input function**

```
/*function - prompt user to enter information*/
void prompt(char * setence , int * shift)
{

 /*Input sentence & shift amount*/

 printf("Enter a setence:\n");
 gets(setence);


 printf("Enter Shift Amount:\n");
 scanf("%d" , &*shift);


  }
```

**calculation function**

```
/*Function - shift string of characters by shift number*/
void calculation (char *setence , int shift)
{
 /*Iterate through setence , change letter by shift amount.
  If setence character == z , wrap around back through A.*/

 for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(setence); i++)
 {
   if(setence[i] == 'z')
   {
    setence[i] = 'a' + (shift - 1);
   }
   else if (isalpha(setence[i]) && (setence[i] >= 'a' && setence[i] <='z'))
   {
     setence[i] += shift;
   }
   else if (isalpha(setence[i]) && (setence[i] >= 'A' && setence[i] <='Z'))
   {
     setence[i] += shift;
   }
   else if (setence[i] == ' ')
   {
    continue;

   }

   }

   }
```

**Output Function**

```
e/*Function - output shifted setence*/
 void output (char * setence) 
 {
 /*Iterate and print each character of newly shifted setence array.*/

 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(setence); i++)
 {
   printf("%c ", setence[i]);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Side note: Make sure you shift things properly accounting for the overflow (`'a'+2 = 'c'`, but `'z'+2 = ?`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
sent = &setence[LIMIT];
```

you make `sent` point to one place *beyond* the end of the array `setence`. When you then use that pointer as a destination for `gets` (never ***ever*** use `gets`!) you will write out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Having undefined behavior in your program will make it *ill-formed* and invalid.

What's *probably* is happening is probably that you overwrite the pointer `sent` itself, so it no longer point to where you asked it to point, and you will have further problems when you use the pointer.

The simple solution is to remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their *first* element. In other words doing

```
prompt(setence, &shift);
```

is the same as doing

```
prompt(&setence[0], &shift);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. And i will look into alternatives to gets().

Comment: @digitalXmage [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is the natural and portable alternative. Or if you're on a POSIX system (like macOS or Linux) then [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) perhaps.